# When I call Threads.getOrCreateThreadId crash

Tags: android

Android Source Code 6.0

I add a RmsProvider to TelephonyProvider in AndroidManifest.xml like:

```
<provider
    android:name="RmsProvider"
    android:authorities="rms"
    android:exported="true"
    android:multiprocess="false"
    android:singleUser="true"
    android:readPermission="android.permission.READ_SMS"
    android:writePermission="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"
/>
```

Next, I create a demo, test "insert" function.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Rms.BODY, "123444");
values.put(Rms.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(Rms.TIMESTAMP, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
values.put(Rms.READ, true);
values.put(Rms.TYPE, Rms.MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX);
values.put(Rms.STATUS, Rms.STATUS_PENDING);
values.put(Rms.MESSAGE_TYPE, Rms.RMS_MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT);
values.put(Rms.ADDRESS, "13000000223");
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Rms.CONTENT_URI_LOG, values);
```

In RmsProvider.java it will come into "insert" function, because mmssms.db don't have a thread of 13000000223, so it will call

```
threadId = Threads.getOrCreateThreadId(getContext(), "13000000223");
```

to get a threadid. When run to this code, it crash.

Log is:

```
3-03 18:39:34.635  2546  2552 E art     : Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils: java.lang.SecurityException: Proxy package com.android.phone from uid 1001 or calling package com.android.phone from uid 10060 not allowed to perform READ_ICC_SMS
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.app.AppOpsManager.noteProxyOp(AppOpsManager.java:1636)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider.checkPermissionAndAppOp(ContentProvider.java:527)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:549)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.database.sqlite.SqliteWrapper.query(SqliteWrapper.java:59)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.provider.Telephony$Threads.getOrCreateThreadId(Telephony.java:1831)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.provider.Telephony$Threads.getOrCreateThreadId(Telephony.java:1803)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at com.android.providers.telephony.RmsProvider.insert(RmsProvider.java:45)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:263)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:163)
03-03 18:39:34.766  1282  2107 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
--------- beginning of crash
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.deviceapidemo, PID: 2546
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deviceapidemo/com.example.deviceapidemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Proxy package com.android.phone from uid 1001 or calling package com.android.phone from uid 10060 not allowed to perform READ_ICC_SMS
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Proxy package com.android.phone from uid 1001 or calling package com.android.phone from uid 10060 not allowed to perform READ_ICC_SMS
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1231)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.deviceapidemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
03-03 18:39:34.770  2546  2546 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
03-03 18:39:34.844  2573  2573 E QSEECOMD: : Listener: index = 0, hierarchy = 0
03-03 18:39:34.844  2573  2573 E QSEECOMD: : Init dlopen(librpmb.so, RLTD_NOW) is failed....
03-03 18:39:34.845  2573  2573 E QSEECOMD: : ERROR: RPMB_INIT failed, shall not start listener services
```

I also have another test, i use

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Sms.BODY, "1231");
values.put(Sms.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(Sms.ADDRESS, "13000000124");
values.put(Sms.TYPE, Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX);
getContentResolver().insert(Sms.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

to insert a sms, in sms provider alse will call

```
Threads.getOrCreateThreadId(getContext(), address);
```

but it not crash.

My RmsProvider.java is:

```
package com.android.providers.telephony;

import android.app.AppOpsManager;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.provider.Telephony.MmsSms;
import android.provider.Telephony.Threads;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Binder;

public class RmsProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static final String TABLE_RMS = "rms";

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] whereArgs) {

        int count = 0;
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri url) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri url, ContentValues values) {
        Log.i("ireton", "1");
        long threadId = Threads.getOrCreateThreadId(getContext(), "123");
        Log.i("ireton", "2");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        setAppOps(AppOpsManager.OP_READ_ICC_SMS, AppOpsManager.OP_WRITE_ICC_SMS);
        mOpenHelper = MmsSmsDatabaseHelper.getInstance(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projectionIn, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri url, ContentValues values, String where,
            String[] whereArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    private SQLiteOpenHelper mOpenHelper;

    private final static String TAG = "RmsProvider";
    private final static String VND_ANDROID_RMS = "vnd.android.cursor.item/rms";

    private static final int RMS_LOG = 0;

    private static final UriMatcher sURLMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        sURLMatcher.addURI("rms", "rms_log", RMS_LOG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on AOSP (especially on  Nexus 5 device),it seems your build use the official driver bundles from Google, and there are some missing components. there are some drivers and binary that are not included by Google for those devices for android 6.0.1. 
as a solution, you can get the missing binaries from an official ROM/Stock image and inlcude it in the build system.